# Creating GWT Application-Wide Template

Tags: google-app-engine, templates, gwt

I have searched for an easy way to do this but couldn't find a specific example.

I have an application developed in GWT utilizing GAE that I would like to have a standard look at feel for the various pages within the application.

Is there a way to do this utilzing GWT?

Comment: Do you mean style as in CSS, or location of widgets etc?

Comment: Both. Standard headers and footers and also the location of certain widgets like login box, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 ways to doing this in GWT.

1. if you want minor changes to the standards css that ships as default with GWT toolkit, create your own css and include it after `<inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard'/>` in your gwt.xml as a `script` tag.
2. If you want to theme only a specific set of widgets in some specific scenarios then you may subclass them in your project and add your own CSS style class using `addStyleName`
3. If you need a completely fresh look , very different from the standard theme, then remove the standard theme from your module xml and include your own CSS as a replacement.

Choose any one of the above approach combined with Custom UiBinder widgets for reusable composites (if you have any?). Also check `ClientBundle` and `CssResource` usage before you decide on your approach.